# I am getting >> Unexpected error: No library 'Selenium2Library' found

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, python-3.7

I was working on the conversion of Selenium2Library to SeleniumLibrary. because of some issue we decided to keep Selenium2Library and now I see Unexpected error: No library 'Selenium2Library' found. I have below package but I updated eyes to v4.
Anyone faced this issue??

```
from Selenium2Library.utils.librarylistener import LibraryListener

robotframework==3.0.2
robotframework-selenium2library==1.8.0
eyes-common==4.1.24
eyes-core==4.1.24
eyes-selenium==4.1.24
selenium==3.141.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of SeleniumLibrary creates and alias for Selenium2Library. You should do a complete uninstall of SeleniumLibrary and a re-install of Selenium2Library. Maybe you need to downgrade eyes. Also the version of Selenium must match the Selenium2Library maximum supported version.

```
pip install -U --force robotframework-selenium2library==1.8.0
pip install -U --force selenium==2.53.0
```

Remaining with old versions would be more riskier than updating to new versions.

Comment: So If I use SeleniumLibrary, my pip list is below, but I am getting "No library 'SeleniumLibrary' found"

robotframework==3.1.2
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==4.3.0
selenium==3.141.0
eyes-common==4.1.24
eyes-core==4.1.24
eyes-selenium==4.1.24
robotframework-selenium2library==3.0.0

Comment: That list looks fine. You need to be sure there is no confusion with different python versions, and if libraries are installed globally or with `--user` option. This is a simple verification command: `python3 -c "from SeleniumLibrary import __version__; print(__version__);"`
This would also work: `python3 -c "from SeleniumLibrary.utils.librarylistener import LibraryListener; print(LibraryListener);"`